# ORACLE EBS is not populate the table QA_RESULTS_UPDATE_HISTORY

Tags: oracle11g

I don't know why, but unfortunately the ORACLE EBS is not populate the table QA_RESULTS_UPDATE_HISTORY. Someone has an any solution? Or know why this is happen? Thanks a lot.